# what's wrong with my curl to upload multiple files

Tags: curl, upload

I tried running the following curl statement

```
curl --form file[]=@s1.png --form file[]=@s2.png http://api.website.com/upload.php
```

But my upload.php only receives s1.png.  It doesn't get s2.png.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use this hack

```
curl --form "file1=@s1.png" --form "file2=@s2.png" http://api.website.com/upload.php
```